# PHP How to build repairing Stream Wrapper

Tags: php, xml, stream, tidy

I need to repair parts of an XML-Document which is coming in from the internet on the fly, mean I'm using a stream an can't wait until the whole document is loaded because the file is too large and I didn't got that much time :) So I thought about using a stream wrapper but I'm kinda stuck how to implement it, in fact I didn't find a clue on implementing the `stream_read()` and so on -Methods....
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as you're looking for some example code for a Stream-Wrapper class, see [**Example class registered as stream wrapper**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php).

As you have not shared much about the nature of the fixes you want to apply on the streamed data, it's hard to provide more information.

Maybe a [stream filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.filters.php) is something less complex which does the job as well for you. And based on your comments this looks more appropriate as you do not want to care about providing the stream but working with it. See the manual page for [`stream_filter_register()`](http://php.net/function.stream-filter-register) which has an example on how to filter the stream on the fly.

As you have not shared what actually is broken and as XML is a file-format that needs to be fully loaded into memory to deal with it correctly (strictly spoken), I can not say if a stream filter really is appropriate or not.

Strictly spoken: It might not be technically possible what you try to achieve because of the nature of XML.

Comment: Looked at this example but like I mentioned I don't know how to handle the stream_read()

Comment: All I want to do is repairing the xml on the fly

Comment: I've update the answer about the filter because I think that is what you are looking for. BTW what's broken with the XML that needs repair? Wrong encoding? Please give an example in your question.

Comment: I'm using the xmlreader, so it doesn't seem to be a problem that I want to handle a stream, the speed of it is pretty awesome and fully fits my needs. I dug a little into the whole-filter thing, I'm going to catch that thought. Any ideas on how to append the filter to the xmlreader function `code`xmlreader->open()`/code`  Here's the W3C-Validator result http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fes%2Frss%2Ftopfreeapplications%2Flimit%3D300%2Fgenre%3D6014%2Fxml&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: I was already able to compose a function, that is repairing the xml in a proper way, all whats left is to appends this to a stream to handle it on the fly